# PrimeFaces 12 DataExporter xls column headings

Tags: primefaces

When updating PrimeFaces to version 12 DataExporter exports xls file without column headings

```html
<f:facet name="header">
    <div align="center">
        <p:outputPanel style="float: right;">
            <h:commandLink id="gerarXls" styleClass="table-button generateXls">
                <p:graphicImage name="/images/table-icons/file-xls.svg"/>
                <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="datatableOrdemServico" fileName="Ordens de Servico"
                                options="#{dataExporterCustomizedView.excelOpt}"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </div>
</f:facet>

<p:column width="50" style="text-align: center" sortBy="#{ordemServico.codigoOs}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{ordemServico.codigoOs}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Número"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{ordemServico.codigoOs}"/>
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

The missing header is a known [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9290) which is [fixed](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/9291) in PrimeFaces 12.0.1 (Elite) or PrimeFaces 13 (Community).